# How to fix Module Not Found Error in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, modulenotfounderror

So I was importing `fs` module in node.js `const fs = require('fs');` and `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error is coming up... I have googled a lot found no help.

Comment: Are you actually running that code in Node.js? Or are you processing it  using a tool written using Node.js (such as WebPack)?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yha7dCz — under normal circumstances, that code will not cause that error when run with Node.js.

Comment: Try uninstalling node.js clean all node related caches and install the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are in the right directory where the '.js' file is.

Answer (score -4):

`MODULE_NOT_FOUND`, just error name tells you about missing module in your project. Installing modules can be done by `npm i <name module>` so in your consoile type `npm i fs`

Comment: `fs` is a core Node.js module, it is not available on npm.

Comment: I have already done that it doesn't work.